# Is google cloud dns latency based routing?

Tags: dns, google-cloud-dns

I'm testing Google Cloud DNS.

I have 3 A NAMES in my test zone that all resolve to the same DNS name.

The servers are in Australia, Northwest US, and India.

I am located in Northwest US.

When I do a tracert on my DNS name, it goes to the IP in the Australian data center.

From me to the Northwest US data center has much lower latency.

Why does it pick Australia?  I thought latency based routing was "built-in" to an anycast network.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud DNS does not do latency based routing.

The Cloud DNS nameservers are on anycast network, so your DNS queries will be routed to the "nearest" nameserver. See https://cloud.google.com/dns/what-is-cloud-dns#performance_and_timing. Your servers' ip addresses, however, are not on that network.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge Google Cloud DNS doesn't do lowest latency routing.   AWS has regions in the places you mentioned, so it might be worth checking out Route 53. I primarily use GCE for compute resources, but generally use Route 53 for DNS.  http://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/latency-based-multi-region-routing-now-available-for-aws/
http://aws.amazon.com/route53/faqs/#Route_53_anycast

Comment: I'm currently using route 53 and it works great. They don't have site in India though.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 3 A records on the same domain. The nameserver will ALWAYS return all 3 IPs.

Then your computer just pick one of them to ping/traceroute. Same for browsers(browsers will try another if the current one is down).

If you want the nameserver return the nearest server, use AWS Route 53's latency/geo based function.  Google Cloud DNS don't have such function so far.
However if you have all your servers at Google, you may want to try their Load Balancer + CDN. The overall latency and performance is amazing, just like the speed your credit card is burning. lol